# Handle asynchronous events from model to view model

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose a Model that asynchronously fires events (i.e. not from the UI thread). Because this Model has access to a DAQ card and performs time critical tasks it is important that the event handlers do not block/take to long to process the event.

To summarize:

- event handlers shouldn't block while processing the event
- since events are not fired from the UI thread they need to be delegated to the UI thread

By now I created a View Model that uses the `Dispatcher` of the View and `BeginInvoke`. In the code below I try to change a property `IsEmergencyButtonActive` onto which the UI may create a data binding:

```
void board_EmergencyButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, bool state)
{
    uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
        IsEmergencyButtonActive = state;
        // Perform other time consuming tasks ...
    }));
}
```

Is this "the way to go"? Are there better approaches to solve this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there better approaches to solve this task?

Two immediately come to mind.

First is a minor modification to the code you already have: instead of a specific dispatcher, you can use the more generic `SynchronizationContext`:

```
// elsewhere, from the UI thread...
context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

void board_EmergencyButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, bool state)
{
  context.Post(_ =>
  {
    IsEmergencyButtonActive = state;
    // Perform other time consuming tasks ...
  }, null);
}
```

In this simplified code, it wouldn't make any difference. But if this code was in, say, a ViewModel, then taking a dependency on the `SynchronizationContext` is a better choice than taking a dependency on a UI-specific dispatcher type. (Easier to work with in unit tests, more portable if you change to a different UI framework).

The other option - which I prefer - is to treat your stream of events as an Rx stream. So, instead of `EmergencyButtonEvent`, you'd have an `IObservable<bool>`. Then the consuming code would look like:

```
// IObservable<bool> EmergencyButtonStates { get; }
IDisposable subscription = board.EmergencyButtonStates
    .ObserveOn(context) // Same "context" as above. Rx can also use dispatchers, too.
    .Subscribe(state =>
    {
      IsEmergencyButtonActive = state;
      // Perform other time consuming tasks ...
    });
// Dispose "subscription" when you don't want any more events.
```

Rx has a bit more of a learning curve, but it's incredibly powerful. It's especially useful when it comes to any kind of time-related logic. E.g., "throttle this event stream to no more than once every 200ms" or "take the most recent value from this event stream when this other event stream hasn't updated in over a second", which is probably useful given your hardware-based scenario.

Comment: Your solution sounds good, especially Rx looks promissing! However, I came to the conclusion that -- from the the model's POV -- it is a bad approach to expect to view model to not block the event handler for "too long". The model itself should asynchronously fire the events so that it has not to care about what potential listeners do. I think I keep the approach with the SynchronizationContext in the view model **but** I need to fire the model's event itself asynchronous. Any ideas how to do this in a simple manner?

Comment: @user1549233: The easiest way would be to use Rx - it's all about asynchronous event streams. The other option would be to have your model also take a SyncCtx, but I think the Rx solution has a better separation-of-concerns story when talking about the model.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would recommend using async/await. Event Handlers are one of the few scenarios where it is appropriate to use **async void** instead of **async Task**.

```
async void board_EmergencyButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsEmergencyButtonActive = taskBegunState;       
    await Task.Run(() => { ...Long Running Code... });
    IsEmergencyButtonActive = taskCompleteState;
}
```